# Adsense mobile web ads don't work with jQueryMobile

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, ads, adsense

I am trying to put High End mobile ads of Adsense in my jQueryMobile website. Facing problem that whenever user opens the page with ad the only ad shows up in whole page. It wont show inside the page or area i put.

Comment: please edit your question and add some code you are using

Comment: Related: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-b1-now-works-with-admob-ads

Answer (score 0):

Not expert in AdSense but I found this question while searching to integrate ads using InMobi, You can integrate InMobi ads using InMobi Mobile Web SDK as described here:

http://ciitronian.com/blog/programming/javascript/integrating-inmobi-ads-jquerymobile-mosync-based-app/